# How to detect empty string which may include white spaces in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like to detect empty strings and white strings by

```
#!/etc/bash

test_word=' ' # test_word includes only one space

if [[ ${test_word} =~ ^\s*$ ]]; then
  echo "detect"
else
  echo "not detect"
fi
```

The result is

```
not detect
```

It does not work.
Please let me know how to detect it.
Or please let me know some option like

```
if [[ -z ${var} ]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\s` doesn't match whitespace in BASH (it will just match a single leter `s`), you can use POSIX property `[[:blank:]]` to match a space or a tab:

```
if [[ ${test_word} =~ ^[[:blank:]]*$ ]]; then
  echo "detect"
else
  echo "not detect"
fi
```

Here is a non-regex way to detect the same:

```
if [[ -z ${test_word//[[:blank:]]/} ]]; then
    echo "detect"
else
    echo "not detect"
fi
```

`${test_word//[[:blank:]]/}` will remove all the whitespace from `$test_word` and `-z` will check if given string is of zero length.

Here is another `extglob` way to detect the same (thanks to @gniourf_gniourf):

```
if [[ ${test_word} == *([[:blank:]]) ]]; then
    echo "detect"
else
    echo "not detect"
fi
```